# Grunt ftp files to different destination path to source

Tags: node.js, ftp, gruntjs

Hopefully someone can help a grunt newbie (so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious).

I'm using [grunt-ftp-push](https://github.com/Robert-W/grunt-ftp-push) to push a website up to my host.  Thus far I have the following configuration:

```
    ftp_push: {
        website: {
            options: {
                host: "myhost.net",
                dest: "httpdocs/tp",
                username: "user",
                password: "password"
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: ".",
                src: ["deployment/live/website/**"]
            }]
        }
    }
```

Now this does work, but the files get deployed to **httpdocs/tp/deployment/live/website**.

Ideally I want them just deploying to **httpdocs/tp** - in effect grunt ftp is reflecting my build environment and I'd like to strip off the **deployment/live/website** path when files are pushed up to the website.

I've tried numerous variations but can't quite get to what I'm after.  As I say I'm a newbie and I may be missing something really obvious.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you set `cwd` to `deployment/live/website/` and `src` to `**`? Or use `flatten`? http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically

Comment: Would you believe me if I said I've tried every permutation but that one? 
Thanks Greg.

Don't suppose you know how to delete a file over ftp in grunt too do you? :-)

Comment: You could probably just use this instead of that Grunt lib. https://github.com/sergi/jsftp - you'd have more control

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too.  Think I'll just stick with 1 manual step :-)
Thanks for your help though, much appreciated!